# How to compare a child class to it's default values from a call within the base class in PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, inheritance, polymorphism, instance, base-class

Considering this basic code snippet:

```
<?
  class mcClassington
  {
        var $mcProperty='default';

        function mcDoSomething()
        {
               if($this->mcProperty == (/* new type of same class */)->mcProperty)
               {
                       sameBusiness();
               }
               else
               {
                       sortIt($this->mcProprety);
               }
        }
 }
```

Not sure how I can ask for a new object of whichever type the `$this` instance is.

I'm trying to write this function for a base class but let classes which extend from it check against their own default values. All I could think of was super-ghetto using `switch(get_class($this))` but that would completely destroy the dynamic goal of the code I'm working on.

> **EDIT**: So,.. I can't actually post the complete real code. The best I can provide is a static example of usage posted below.

```
class displayObject //implements attachable
{
    public $layer = null;
    public $xPos = Array(
                        'left'=>null, 
                        'width'=>null,
                        'margin-left'=>null,
                        'margin-right'=>null,
                        'padding-left'=>null,
                        'padding-right'=>null
                    );
    public $yPos = Array(
                        'top'=>null,
                        'height'=>null,
                        'margin-top'=>null,
                        'margin-bottom'=>null,
                        'padding-top'=>null,
                        'padding-bottom'=>null
                    );
}


class Button extends displayObject
{
    public $link, $image, $backing;
    public $xPos = Array(
                        'left'=>null, 
                        'width'=>'120px',
                        'margin-left'=>'8px',
                        'margin-right'=>'8px',
                        'padding-left'=>null,
                        'padding-right'=>null
                    );
    public $yPos = Array(
                        'top'=>null,
                        'height'=>'108px',
                        'margin-top'=>'4px',
                        'margin-bottom'=>'4px',
                        'padding-top'=>null,
                        'padding-bottom'=>null
                    );
}
```

**And then, in other files people might use the class like so:**

```
$navBar = Array();  // Will hold basic Button Objects

$specialtyButton = new Button();
$specialtyButton->$xPos['width'] = '220px';
$specialtyButton->$yPos['height'] = '220px';
/*  and so on...    */
```

The function I'm writing must be called from within the base class displayObject in the format `myFunction($this);` What I'm trying to solve is sorting the pseudo-styles into different places based on whether or not they are the same as their default values.

For instance, $specialtyButton would be sorted specially because it's width and height differed from Button's default values but the Buttons inside $navBar would be overlooked because nothing was set explicitly.

Comment: You should _never_ use `var` in new code. This is a relic from the PHP <= 4 days. Also, _always_ explicitly declare the visibility of properties and methods.

Comment: The question is rather confusing. Can you please give an example of intended usage?

Comment: it's a bit confusing kindly provide an example of a child class that would able to inherit this class and specifically explain what you really want to happen like do you want to compare the instance values, and etc

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Radu Sorry, you're right of course I was just being lazy in my thought process.

Comment: @j_mcnally and colighto using php 5.2,... I'll try to post some more relevant code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply:

```
$myClassName = get_class($this);
$newObj = new $myClassName;
if ($this->mcProperty == $newObj->mcProperty) {
  // ...
```

...but I wouldn't. I would say it would be more sensible to hold the default values in a `private` property, so no-one can modify them, and compare against them instead. Creating new instances just to check if values are default seems like a horrible thing to do to me...

Comment: I can definitely see your point from a performance point of view; this script is not performance sensitive however. Basically the goal is to avoid the need to explicitly redefine properties. In a world with more time there will be a class tracker that handles this later and preserves a blank state copy..

Comment: So you can just run `new string`?

Comment: What if you had a private `array()` of all the default values, then in the constructor you can just `foreach ($this->defaults as $name => $val) $this->$name = $val;` - and when you want to check whether they are default you could `private function is_default ($name) { return $this->$name === $this->defaults[$name]; }` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would change your format to something like this:

```
class mcClassington
{
    private $mcProperty = array( 'value' => '', 'default' => 0);

    function mcDoSomething()
    {
        if($this->mcProperty['value'] == $this->mcProperty['default'])
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, either define the `default` value as an array key inside the same class member, or create another class member for the default value, like `private $mcPropertyDefault;`.

Comment: I think this would work equally well. Would somewhat like to avoid making each property an array explicitly, however.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the keyword parent in your child class that is inheriting the object example:

```
parent::xPos;
```

the parent will point to the parent class but not sure if it would work with properties the way it would work with methods though cause I was only able to use this keyword for accessing the original method from the parent class when I'm trying to override some of it's methods and I want to add a new process to it, but if that won't work I think another best option is to use the concept of encapsulation creating a method for setting and getting the property value and making the name of that property different of that from your child class to preserve the default value from the parent class, then on the setter you could now check whether the values to be set are default or not.